# Access Prestashop webservice from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, web-services, cordova, prestashop

In the Prestashop backend I activated the webservice and I created an authentication key. Testing in browser works well but now I want to access the webservice via JavaScript in a Cordova application.

The response I am getting is `401 (Unauthorized)`. I'm performing this ajax call (using AngularJS):

```
$http.get('http://AUTHENTICATION_KEY@url.com/api/employees/2', {})
```

How do I have to send the authentication key?

I've been searching on the Internet but I did not found anything interesting that solves my problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally, I figured out how to send the ws_key:

```
$http({
        method: 'get',
        url: ws_url + 'customers/?schema=blank',
        params: {
            ws_key: ws_key
        });
```

You have to pass the ws_key param with your key to access the PrestaShop webservice.

Answer (score 1):

Although i am not php guy and i haven not used prestashop ever, but may be you forgot provide access in your crodova application this might be the issue please add

```
<access origin="*"/>
```

this to your config.xml file hopefully it will work thanks, please do not forgot mark as an answer if it helps you..

Comment: Finally I figured out how to access the webservice, digging in the PrestaShop webservice files, I found that I have to send the authentication key as a parameter named ws_key.