# Calling Prestashop webservice from jquery Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, web-services, prestashop

I need to call a prestashop webservice from another page using jquery ajax. But I am unable to access it. It gives me `404` error in every case. Can't exactly figure out as very limited information is available over the internet in this regard. Though I found one somewhat [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24798902/acces-prestashop-webservice-from-javascript) but that didn't worked either.

The [Documentation](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Web+service+one-page+documentation) tells about doing it with PHP but not with jquery

Here is my code:

```
$.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost:81/prestashop/api/products",
            method : "GET",
            data : 
                {
                    ws_key : "XHDSHJH4334HHSDBMT77ASDUUY689"
                }
        }).success(function(){
            alert("success");
        }).error(function(){
            alert("error");
        })
```

The error I am getting is this:

```
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost:81/prestashop/api/products?ws_key=XHDSHJH4334HHSDBMT77ASDUUY689"
```

Comment: Well your Error indicates your resource can't be found, means it simply appears to not be there. Check if your server is running correctly, the URL is right and check manually if you can access the webservice. Sole AJAX should not be causing a 404 error.

Answer (score 0):

Ok... Got the answer finally. The problem was that the prestashop wasn't set to use friendly urls and this was actually causing the problem.

I had to set prestashop to use friendly url and that resolved the issue.

[image]