# How to add products in Prestashop webservice API using javascript?

Tags: javascript, web-services, prestashop

I'm trying to figure out how to add products Prestashop or anything else really using the webservice API.

I saw this question here which helped me getting started and getting info out of the API.

[Acces Prestashop webservice from JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24798902/acces-prestashop-webservice-from-javascript)

But now I'm trying to use it to send XML data and add stuff.

I used the 'hurl.it' to test a lot of things but still no sucess.

If someone can give some pointers I would be greatly apretiated! :)

**update:**

using the param "postXml" I get the same issues.

[image: request]

[image: response]

Comment: how you are passing the xml data, please try sending your xml data with param "postXml"

Comment: i was using a param "xml"

Comment: I added screens showing the error i get